# GWTP how to execute code on application initialization/start

Tags: gwtp, gwt-platform, gwt-places

I would like to execute asynchronous call to the server when the application starts (have been loaded in users browser).

To communicate with server I use RestyGWT.

On application start I wanna call server to check is user logged in (is his cookie/token is still valid)?
If token is still valid, I would like to redirect user to page for logged in users. If not I would like to redirect to `login` page

I would like to work this also for **inside client app urls**, for example: `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/admin`. When I enter this url from inside app it work. When I enters this url it redirect me to default page.

Please help.

Here is my service execution code:

```
service.isCurrentUserLoggedIn(new MethodCallback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
    MaterialToast.fireToast("Fail to check is current user logged in " + method + " " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Method method, Boolean response) {
    currentUser.setLoggedIn(response);
    getView().setLoginButtonVisbility(response);
    }
});
```

I've done this in AppPresenter in class constructor, but this is I think wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create own `Bootstrapper` class that implements `com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Bootstrapper`

and inside this class implement method `void onBootstrap()` where I execute `service.isCurrentUserLoggedIn(new MethodCallback<Boolean>() {})`
and then base on answer result, redirect to login or current place.

[Here is official documentation.](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/get-started/Bootstrap-Code.html#bootstrapper)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be enough if you move out of the constructor and into the onBind() method. Though I'm assuming this is in your presenter revealed in root and your other presenters are revealed in the root presenters slots.